# 2002 Volvo C70 won't start on first try

Tags: starting, volvo

My C70 turns over but won't fire. I let it sit for a minute or less and it fires right up. This problem is becoming more and  more frequent. Once it starts the car is great for the rest of the day.

Answer (score 2):

Possible condensation/moisture in an ignition component.  I've located similar problems in the past by lightly misting the various components with a spray water bottle until I find the cracked part.

Comment: My mechanic is saying ignition also but why does it always start on the second try (a minute or so later)? Wouldn't that indicate a fuel problem?

Comment: How do you get to fuel problem (honest question here, wondering if there's some other symptom that you're picking up on that I'm not catching in the question)?  My thoughts, based on the current data are:  What would be different about the fuel after waiting a minute?  If you aren't getting fuel pressure after several cranks, you're not going to.  One thing about ignition components is that arcing will burn off some moisture, after which they may then function.

Comment: Brian, what you say makes sense. Guess I'll go with you and my mechanic. My thought was that if your car is flooded it usually won't start but if you wait a minute or two it will.Although there is no fuel smell.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem. My fuel pump was faulty. Eventually it got worse and worse u til I finally had to replace the fuel pump and sensor and filter. I have a 1993 940 Volvo sedan. Remember that Volvos do not always behave or react to symptoms in the same way that American cars do. Best to go with a mechanic who knows Volvos.